# FirebaseListAdapter equivalent for com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now Firebase is changed to Google FirebaseDatabase. https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered

I could not find equivalent for FirebaseListAdapter.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this documentation:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

```
dependencies {
    # Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
}
```

And then you can instantiate the FirebaseListAdapter class like the old code examples show.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The new package is called firebase-ui-database. Refer https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md